# user.isModified is not a function when doing a pre update in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I'm trying to hash passwords in an app I'm building and they are hashing fine when I create a user by calling this function(coffeesctipt):

```
UserSchema.pre 'save', (next) ->
  user = this
  hashPass(user, next)

hashPass = (user, next) ->
  # only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
  if !user.isModified('password')
    return next()
  # generate a salt
  bcrypt.genSalt SALT_WORK_FACTOR, (err, salt) ->
    if err
      return next(err)
    # hash the password using our new salt
    bcrypt.hash user.password, salt, (err, hash) ->
      if err
        return next(err)
      # override the cleartext password with the hashed one
      user.password = hash
      next()
      return
    return
```

but when I do an update and have this pre:

```
UserSchema.pre 'findOneAndUpdate', (next) ->
  user = this
  hashPass(user, next)
```

I get `TypeError: user.isModified is not a function` if I console log user in the pres the save pre logs the user I am updating, the findandupdate pre does not,id there to way to access the document in the pre or do I need to do this another way?

### NOTE:  The above functions are NOT arrow functions.  They are normal functions written in CoffeeScript with ->, they compile into js with normal functions.

Comment: I think your problem is that `this` in the `.pre('update')` hook refers to the `Query` object instead of the model itself: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes

Comment: make it regular function instead of arrow function, arrow function changes the scope of this.

Answer (score 27):

You get an error because the arrow function changes the scope of 'this.' 
Just use

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){})
```

Comment: The question is in CoffeeScript, CoffeeScript compiles the arrow function into `UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){})` not into a js arrow function

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when using middleware in mongoose, in that case of "save" or "updateOne", `this` refers to a query, not a document. It should look like this

```
schema.pre(type, { document: true, query: false }, async function (next) 
{
     if(this.isModified('password')) {
            //Do the hash
     }
     next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on typescript and it turns out that is was related to the arrow operator you are also using. Not sure how to change this in coffescript right now but I think that should fix your issue.

you have to change this line:

```
hashPass = (user, next) ->
```

Check this out: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4537

Comment: `->` is just the way you write functions in coffeescript, it compiles down to a normal function not one with `=>`

Comment: Your issue was exact same issue I had. The github issue I linked in my answer explain you the reason why. Check it out.

Comment: I did check it out, `UserSchema.pre 'findOneAndUpdate', (next) ->` in coffee compiles to `UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {` so there is literally nothing I could change in my code to make it work based off that solution.  My problem is due to fact that Model.pre 'findOneAndUpdate' returns a different `this` than a Model.pre 'save' does.  A pre 'save' returns the user as 'this' and pre on findOneAndUpdate does not.

Comment: I see, I was doing some more research and it looks like it is not possible to accomplish what you are trying to do according to this discussion: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/964. On the thread there are some suggestions you can use

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the arrow operator for the callback, that'll change the scope **this**. Define a regular function; it may help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be way too late for you, but for any future coders that land on this issue, I think this solution should work.
So, since save() is a middleware inside .pre, that overrides some of mongoose's methods, such as findByIDAndUpdate. What you might want to do is instead of using that, break your code up like this if you have patch request firing off somewhere:

```
const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    updates.forEach((update) => {
      user[update] = req.body[update];
    });
```